# Crash opening 2.8 project in 2.18

Tags: qgis, error

When I open an old project (QGIS version 2.8.9) with QGIS 2.18.10, I catch an error that says:

Project file is older : this project file was saved by an older version of QGIS. when saving this project file, QGIS will update latest version, possibly rendering it useless ...

After that QGIS crashes. How can I fix it?

Comment: That is quite a major gap between two versions. Hard to say without knowing more about what your project contains but one likely issue is due to the [depreciation of some functions](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/deprecated.html).

Comment: i was working on geological maps and shapfile . but when i add new raster related to .tiff format . this error shows up

Comment: how can i found which function exactly is the problem ?

Comment: Can you load your old project successfully in QGIS 2.18 (without adding or changing anything)?

Comment: no . i can`t . when in load it that error i say show it up.

Comment: Don't think there's much you can do except building your project again...

Comment: oh !.no . that is quiet hard . because i have lots of layers and styles.

Comment: Does the project load and throw an error, or just throw the error and not show the map data? If you can get the project to load, and you can see your data just fine, then simply click 'save' and you won't get that error any more - the project is not a 2.18 project...

Comment: my project is too heavy  . 4 or 5 min long its late to open and in when the layers are loading i can see them . but suddenly  error comes . and qgis closed .

Comment: Sounds like an issue which needs to be opened on http://issues.qgis.org//issues . Attach your project and the qgis devs can see what's happening.

Comment: For a quick fix in the meantime, try opening and saving your project file in a version of QGIS between 2.8 and 2.18. If that works, work your way up through successively newer versions until you get to 2.18.

Comment: i use to open it by 2.14 and still no working. same error on 2.18